# Bootstrap is unresponsive in tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

My website works on all devices except for tablets. I am using bootstrap 4, and below I have attached the media query for the responsive design.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  div#about {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  div#about img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  div#about-section img {
    margin-bottom: 50px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would advise against creating your own breakpoints if you are using bootstrap. Use their breakpoints to create a consistent behaviour of your site.

Answer (score 2):

You should use min-width, not max-width. I guess the resolution of your tablet is just higher than 1024px, therefore it doesn't apply to the tablet.
Since you use Bootstrap, you should make use of [Bootstrap breakpoints in Sass](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints). This makes your layout consistent with the rest of Bootstrap. They also don't use screen as well.
Otherwise, there is a [stackoverflow question about this issue as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile).

Comment: The website also breaks at 793px. 
shown here: https://gyazo.com/a424390c74618193a2c7be7f3f598f0d

Answer (score 0):

You have to use min-width, but you can't only target 1024px only because of tablets with different screen sizes.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  div#about img {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
      margin: auto !important;
      margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  div#about-section img {
      margin-bottom: 50px !important;
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Recommended screen sizes and media queries for the better experience .

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  
} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  
} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
 
}
```